# Delete data from postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I use postgres with jdbc and I would like to delete all data from database without dropping any tables!!
I would like to insert data in database using this

```
 <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="DataSource"> 
 <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/test.sql"/> 
 </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

the problem is that I got a key duplicated exception, so I have to delete all data before running this code
any idea?

Comment: You can dump the DB (with `pg_dump`) and restore it without table content. Only table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `TRUNCATE your_table;` for all your tables at the beginning of your `test.sql` file.